# Como hacer que ciertos campos solo sean requeridos solo si activo un boton

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Estoy creando el form del perfil de usuario y me choque con el problema de como editar la contraseña. lo primero que se me ocurrio es algo sencillo, crear un boton colapsado, que despliegue el tipico ingreso de la pass actual y de la nueva (con confirmacion)

En principio agregue el required tanto por php como en rules. Pero tal vez deba generar la verificacion desde el controlador y mandar mensajes flash

Mi pregunta es que si de alguna forma, con js o algo, que cuando apriete el boton para modificar la password, se active el required de php.

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'miperfil.store','method'=>'POST']) !!}

    <div class="form-group">        
        {!! Form::label('name','Nombre:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name',Auth::user()->name,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Nombre Completo','required']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email','Correo Electronico:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('email',Auth::user()->email,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'ejemplo@gmail.com','required']) !!}
    </div>

    <button aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-warning" style="margin-top: 5px;" data-target="#collapseExample" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
    Cambiar Password
    </button>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('pass','Contraseña Actual:') !!}
            {!! Form::password('pass',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'*****************']) !!}
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('password','Contraseña Nueva:') !!}
            {!! Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'*****************']) !!}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('password_confirmation','Repetir Contraseña:') !!}
            {!! Form::password('password_confirmation',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'*****************']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <br>
        {!! Form::submit('Registrar Cambios',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}

    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Les saque los required a los campos password, ya que active o no active el boton me los pide igual.

Aqui las reglas

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:60',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'pass' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:3|max:60|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a "activar" la validación de Laravel si el botón está "activo"?

Comment: claro, seria una forma tambien, se puede hacer? yo pensaba algo en principio el required definido como clase en los campos password, pero si se pueden activar o desactivar las validaciones mejor aun

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres inicialmente es agregar el atributo `required` al campo html si está "activo" el botón? No me queda clara esa primera etapa.

Comment: Si. es mi idea, tambien segun se comenta, no solo hay que conformarse con el atributo de html, por eso habia creado la validacion, pero en caso de que sea muy complicado, la hacia manualmente desde el controlador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, una que suelo utilizar es agregar un campo extra, puede ser un checkbox o un campo oculto.

Para la parte de frontend necesitas apoyarte en JavaScript, en este caso te doy un ejemplo rápido con jQuery que posiblemente se pueda mejorar:

```
{!! Form::hidden('enable_pass', 0, ['id' => 'enable_pass']) !!}

$("button").click(function(){

  var enablePass = $("#enable_pass");
  var passFields = $("[type=password]");

  if (enablePass.val() == 0) {
    enablePass.val(1);
    passFields.attr('required', 'required');
  } else {
    enablePass.val(0);
    passFields.removeAttr('required');
  }
});
```

---

Ya en la parte de validación del Request de Laravel usarías la regla `required_if` para relacionar los campos de clave con nuestro campo oculto y su valor:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name'     => 'required|string|min:3|max:60',
        'email'    => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'pass'     => 'required_if:enable_pass,1',
        'password' => 'required_if:enable_pass,1|min:3|max:60|confirmed'
    ];
}
```

Si necesitas otra validación más compleja según el método que apliques, recuerda que en el método rules() puedes jugar con la información del request siempre y cuando devuelvas un array.

Comment: no pude hacer andar este ejemplo, encontre una solucion a medias, usando disabled, pero tengo el problema, cuando hago click en el boton le remueve el disabled, ahora si le hago otro click, no se me ocurre como devolverle el disabled (con 2 botones funciona barbaro). ahora coloco la coloco a la solucion

Comment: Qué fue lo que no funcionó?

Comment: la parte de jquery. no le pude encontrar el problema tampoco

Comment: Yo lo probé antes de ponerlo acá y todo funcionó sin problema. Habría que buscar dónde está el error.

Comment: nunca use una funcion asi en jquery. Talvez estoy manejando mal "button" esta correcto llamarlo asi? siempre le puse un . o un # dependiendo como lo llame

Comment: Ese es el selector del tag respectivo <button> , sin embargo la idea es que adaptes la solución a tu escenario.

Answer (score 0):

Esta forma me anduvo pero no del todo correcta.
Recurriendo a un ejemplo mas reducido del primero..

```
<button aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-warning boton" style="margin-top: 5px;" data-target="#collapseExample" data-toggle="collapse" type="button" onclick="habilita()">
    Cambiar Password
    </button>

    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <br>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('pass','Contraseña Actual:') !!}
            {!! Form::password('pass',['class'=>'form-control inputText','placeholder'=>'*****************','disabled','required']) !!}
        </div>
    </div>

@section('js')
<script>

function habilita(){

    $(".inputText").removeAttr("disabled");

}

function deshabilita(){

    $(".inputText").attr("disabled","disabled");

}
</script>
@endsection
```

Esta es la otra solucion que encontre pero el tema es que necesitaria 2 botones, otro para la funcion deshabilita().

O bien si se puede, poner una especie de bandera para que el proximo clic tome deshabilita(), pero escapa de mis conocimiento

Comment: Todo eso se soluciona agregando los handlers de eventos como está en mi respuesta, realmente no es complicado, hay bastante documentación y tutoriales en la web al respecto, incluso otras preguntas en stackoverflow.